# GITLAB-CI - Join network created by docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab, dockerfile, gitlab-ci

I am creating a gitlab-ci to run e2e tests over my application, 
so, given I have this docker-compose.yml:

```js
services:
  chrome:
    image: zenika/alpine-chrome:latest
    command: [
      chromium-browser,
      "--headless",
      "--no-sandbox",
      "--disable-gpu",
      "--ignore-certificate-errors",
      "--reduce-security-for-testing",
      "--remote-debugging-address=0.0.0.0",
      "--remote-debugging-port=9222",
      "https://google.com/",
    ]
    ports:
      - "9222:9222"
    networks:
      - test-e2e

networks:
  test-e2e:
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.28.0.0/16
```

when I run `docker-compose up` everything just works fine,
and on my local machine I am able to visit `localhost:9222` and access the chrome debugger.

---

**However, when I run the same job on gitlab-ci I get a ECONNREFUSED error**:

```js
F---F

Failures:

1) Scenario: List of Profiles # src/features/profile.feature:3
   ✖ Before # dist/node/development/webpack:/hooks/puppeteer.hooks.ts:17
       Failed to fetch browser webSocket url from http://localhost:9222/json/version: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9222
       Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9222
           at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1191:14)
```

---

So it is clear that **I cannot join the docker-compose network and access `localhost:9222` from the job**

My `gitlab-ci.yml` is pretty straightforward and looks like this:

```js
E2E tests:
  stage: test end-to-end
  image:
    name: docker/compose:1.24.1
    entrypoint: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
  services:
    - docker:dind
  before_script:
    - apk --update add nodejs yarn
    - docker-compose -f test-e2e.yaml up -d
  script:
    - yarn test:cucumber
  after_script:
    - docker-compose -f test-e2e.yaml down
```

`yarn test:cucumber` basically runs cucumber and puppeteer trying to access `localhost:9222` to get chrome's metadata.

---

#### How can I join the network created by docker-compose from the gitlab-ci job?

- I don't have access to edit runner configurations

Comment: Did you solve this? I am facing similar issues. I have few containers in my docker-compose linked in a network, some of them have aliases on that network. I am not getting ECONNREFUSED error, but rather the aliasing/network doesnt seem to exist and my containers call actual services rather than other/aliased containers.

Comment: Nope, but @pierre's answer looks pretty good and I am willing to accept it.

Answer (score 14):

**TL; DR** On CI your `chrome` container is reachable using `docker:9222` (or more generally `<name-of-the-dind-service-on-ci>:<exposed-port>`), not `localhost:9222`

**Explanation**

As per your `gitlab-ci.yml`, you will start 2 containers:

- a `docker/compose:1.24.1` container from which you will run `docker-compose` and `yarn` commands
- a `docker:dind` on which a [Docker Daemon will run](https://docs.docker.com/engine/docker-overview/#the-docker-daemon). This container will be reachable from `docker/compose:1.24.1` container via hostname `docker` ([see GitlabCI doc on accessing services](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#accessing-the-services))

When running a container in Docker, the container is actually started **by the Docker daemon** and will run and expose ports on the host on which the Daemon is running.

- On your machine, the Docker daemon is running locally and will expose the container ports on your local network, allowing you to reach your `chrome` container via `localhost`
- On the CI, you are running your commands from a `docker/compose:1.24.1` container but the Docker daemon is running in another container (a different host): the `docker:dind` container. `chrome` container will be **created inside `docker:dind`** container and its port exposed from this same container. You simply need to access the `docker:dind` container which will expose `chrome` ports.

By using `localhost` from your `docker/compose:1.24.1` container, you won't be able to reach `chrome` because its port is not exposed on `docker/compose:1.24.1` container but from `docker:dind` container. You need to specify its host (`docker`) and the exposed port (`9222`)

Comment: What if my `docker/compose:1.24.1` is connected to network `build-network`. Is there a way to connect `docker:dind` to this network too?

Comment: What do you mean "connect to network `build-network`" ? If you setup a network on runner level (`config.toml`), then both service and job container would be on the defined network

Comment: Thanks Pierre. Yeah, I meant exactly this. After your response I had rechecked my stack and understood that `docker:dind` did not use DNS server on `build-network`. Now I adjust my `/etc/resolve.conf` inside `docker:dind` from `before_script` every thing works fine. Thank you for pointing it out: `docker/compose:1.24.1` and `build-network` are on the same network, defined via `network_mode`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using gitlab shared runners, probably you are not allowed to create networks for security reasons.

Try using your own private runners. It is really easy to set up them: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/

An alternative is [services](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#services).

Answer (score -1):

I think good idea is to start

```
docker-compose up
```

inside CI script.

After it you will be able to access. And if you run CI again it will start same containers.