# How to make https requests to a web app running on docker containers in a gitlab CI/CD pipeline?

Tags: java, docker, networking, gitlab-ci

I am trying to run some security tests agains a web app I have running in a gitlab pipeline.  The app critically needs Semgrep, Docker Compose and some custom security software to run.

Here is my pipeline file https://gitlab.com/alex-nightvision1/java-github-actions-demo/-/blob/main/.gitlab-ci.yml?ref_type=heads

All relevant software can be downloaded and run with this pipeline.  However, when I try to add tests within the pipeline steps that can make basic https requests like ping or curl it seems there's something wrong with the networking component.

How do I add something so my steps can connect and make https requests to an app running in a docker container on https://127.0.0.1:9000 within the pipeline? Is it something I need to do with the `/etc/hosts` file?

Example output of my current job:

https://gitlab.com/alex-nightvision1/java-github-actions-demo/-/jobs/5798178141#L1655-L1764

```
$ docker-compose up -d
Creating network "java-github-actions-demo_default" with the default driver
Pulling db (postgres:)...
latest: Pulling from library/postgres
Digest: sha256:01cc58ff77e6e4e21999c8afff1b21954a131054c48db5269a8e6589701cc3ba
Status: Downloaded newer image for postgres:latest
Building javavulny
DEPRECATED: The legacy builder is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
            Install the buildx component to build images with BuildKit:
            https://docs.docker.com/go/buildx/
Step 1/8 : FROM openjdk:11.0.10-jdk-slim
11.0.10-jdk-slim: Pulling from library/openjdk
f7ec5a41d630: Pulling fs layer
faf4c47c8c61: Pulling fs layer
810072571faf: Pulling fs layer
4b3fe8e4a3b9: Pulling fs layer
4b3fe8e4a3b9: Waiting
810072571faf: Verifying Checksum
810072571faf: Download complete
faf4c47c8c61: Verifying Checksum
faf4c47c8c61: Download complete
f7ec5a41d630: Verifying Checksum
f7ec5a41d630: Download complete
4b3fe8e4a3b9: Verifying Checksum
4b3fe8e4a3b9: Download complete
f7ec5a41d630: Pull complete
faf4c47c8c61: Pull complete
810072571faf: Pull complete
4b3fe8e4a3b9: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:0c1702c4b90c6148a9856d3154963b7499eb9efca1687ad544340f1542c85b9f
Status: Downloaded newer image for openjdk:11.0.10-jdk-slim
 ---> b4517d9514cb
Step 2/8 : RUN mkdir /javavulny /app
 ---> Running in 6508e0856116
Removing intermediate container 6508e0856116
 ---> e77e2f1d8ce4
Step 3/8 : COPY . /javavulny/
 ---> 0b249427c4c3
Step 4/8 : RUN sed -i 's/localhost\:5432/db\:5432/' /javavulny/src/main/resources/application-postgresql.properties
 ---> Running in af2118e831e2
Removing intermediate container af2118e831e2
 ---> 615f30a3ce47
Step 5/8 : RUN cd /javavulny && ./gradlew --no-daemon build && cp build/libs/java-spring-vuly-0.1.0.jar /app/ && rm -Rf build/ && cd / && rm -Rf /javavulny /root/.gradle/
 ---> Running in f15e4f80e690
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5.1-bin.zip
...........10%............20%...........30%............40%...........50%............60%...........70%............80%...........90%............100%
Welcome to Gradle 7.5.1!
Here are the highlights of this release:
 - Support for Java 18
 - Support for building with Groovy 4
 - Much more responsive continuous builds
 - Improved diagnostics for dependency resolution
For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/release-notes.html
To honour the JVM settings for this build a single-use Daemon process will be forked. See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:disabling_the_daemon.
Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build 
> Task :compileJava
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /javavulny/src/main/java/hawk/controller/PayloadController.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
> Task :processResources
> Task :classes
> Task :bootJar
> Task :distTar NO-SOURCE
> Task :distZip NO-SOURCE
> Task :jar SKIPPED
> Task :assemble
> Task :compileTestJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :processTestResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :testClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :test NO-SOURCE
> Task :check UP-TO-DATE
> Task :build
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 43s
3 actionable tasks: 3 executed
Removing intermediate container f15e4f80e690
 ---> dc9224c8aa07
Step 6/8 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Running in 8f73c46d7e85
Removing intermediate container 8f73c46d7e85
 ---> 7c47b2079eb0
Step 7/8 : ENV PWD=/app
 ---> Running in c4445c76b2f5
Removing intermediate container c4445c76b2f5
 ---> 013cce8ec634
Step 8/8 : CMD ["java", "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom", "-jar", "/app/java-spring-vuly-0.1.0.jar"]
 ---> Running in 7cf06d01d1e9
Removing intermediate container 7cf06d01d1e9
 ---> 7bcef5d3b110
Successfully built 7bcef5d3b110
Successfully tagged stackhawk/javavulny:latest
Image for service javavulny was built because it did not already exist. To rebuild this image you must use `docker-compose build` or `docker-compose up --build`.
Creating java-github-actions-demo_db_1 ... 
Creating java-github-actions-demo_db_1 ... done
Creating javavulny                     ... 
Creating javavulny                     ... done
$ sleep 10
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                        COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                                       NAMES
fa34b64d241a   stackhawk/javavulny:latest   "java -Djava.securit…"   10 seconds ago   Up 10 seconds   0.0.0.0:9000->9000/tcp, :::9000->9000/tcp   javavulny
cec9a90873de   postgres                     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   10 seconds ago   Up 10 seconds   0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp, :::5432->5432/tcp   java-github-actions-demo_db_1
$ docker network ls
NETWORK ID     NAME                               DRIVER    SCOPE
776da0ca6ccd   bridge                             bridge    local
45e1bf558a3e   host                               host      local
ad8c9d54c9f7   java-github-actions-demo_default   bridge    local
bbf033f8208c   none                               null      local
$ curl -k https://127.0.0.1:9000
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 9000 after 0 ms: Connection refused
```

Here is the output.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [problem connecting to docker container from gitlab-runner container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69794986/problem-connecting-to-docker-container-from-gitlab-runner-container)

Comment: Not for me, but its a start. I think the main change there is to use the alias `docker` instead of `localhost`.  In the comments on that other post it seems the user resolved the issue by using an http site `docker run --rm -d -it -p 8000:80 strm/helloworld-http`.  However I need to run this specific application which uses https only and replacing localhost with docker did not work.

Comment: Can you provide logs from `javavulny` container? is it for sure listening on port 9000? as you `DOCKER_HOST` using `docker` as hostname it should work

Comment: @zori can you see it here? https://gitlab.com/alex-nightvision1/java-github-actions-demo/-/jobs/5954399427

Comment: I don't see issues but I have two ideas, you have service `docker:dind` twice, one is global second is at `job` level, try remove one of it, also you can try use `nslookup docker` to verify is it resolving to any IP

Comment: So I think this is the start to the probelm nslookup always fails whenever i point it at docker ```$ nslookup docker
Server:  169.254.169.254
Address: 169.254.169.254#53
** server can't find docker: NXDOMAIN``` Is there a way to map the docker network to the localhost or some way around this?

Comment: I didn't get notification about your last message, did you resolve it? I'm curious

Answer (score 0):

I think your configuration has 2 issues:

- `curl` is using `localhost` instead of `docker` to connect to your container (though it seems [you fixed it](https://gitlab.com/alex-nightvision1/java-github-actions-demo/-/commit/0c051decbb09e3b39b0ec1954e25ec5b9c8130f7) recently). You should use `curl -k https://docker:9000`

  - You are running a `docker:dind` service, and your app container runs inside this other container. `docker` service is reachable via `docker` hostname from your CI job, and your app's container is running *inside* this container, listening on port `9000`
  - See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56784919/gitlab-ci-join-network-created-by-docker-compose/58645585#58645585) and [GitLab doc on accessing service](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/services/#accessing-the-services)
- `curl ...:9000` is probably running before your app is completely started (it does not yet listen on port `9000`), hence the `connection refused`. Spring is known to be slow to start, this is confirmed by [logs in your pipelines](https://gitlab.com/alex-nightvision1/java-github-actions-demo/-/jobs/5959886456) where typical "startup OK" lines like `Tomcat started` or `Started Application` are not shown. Spring apps will typically show logs like this after successful startup:

  ```
  2024-01-20 10:00:04.234  INFO 9999 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 9000 (http) with context path ''
  2024-01-20 10:00:04.345  INFO 9999 --- [           main] com.example.demo.Application             : Started Application in 40.420 seconds (JVM running for 40.475)
  ```

You could `sleep` longer before running `curl` but it's gonna be painful to wait on each pipelines. A better fail-fast approach is to leverage `docker compose --wait` and healthcheck on your app container to ensure your application is healthy (fully started) before running your tests:

- Update your `docker-compose.yml` with a healthcheck such as

  ```yaml
    javavulny:
      # ...
      # Wait up to 3 min for app to start 
      # and be responsive on port 9000
      healthcheck:
        test: ["CMD", "curl", "-k", "https://localhost:9000"]
        interval: 10s
        timeout: 5s
        retries: 18
  ```
- Wait for successful startup with `docker-compose up -d --wait` and remove `sleep 10`
- Use `curl -k https://docker:9000` instead of `curl -k https://localhost:9000` to reach the DinD container where your app container is running

Now, Docker Compose will wait for app to be ready and accepting requests on port `9000`. Your subsequent `curl -k https://docker:9000` will likely succeed.

Comment: I think the larger problem isn't the app its that I cannot connect to the `docker` hostname.  I need some method of running my container on a network with a hostname or ip the scripts in my pipeline can actually use.

Comment: `docker` is the hostname of your `docker:dind` service, in which your Java app is running - you are already using it with `DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375/` variable on CI ;) Consider your `docker:dind` as a VM with hostname `docker`, on this VM Docker daemon is running on port `2375` (it works since your can run your app container). Then, your app container open port `9000` on your VM, hence reachable via `docker:9000`.  A schema/image will speak better than 1000 words, if this is still not clear tell me I'll edit my answer with an image.

Answer (score 0):

To make HTTPS requests to a web app running on Docker containers in a GitLab CI/CD pipeline, you can follow these general steps. The specific implementation might vary based on your application, Docker setup, and infrastructure. Here's a simplified example assuming you are using GitLab CI/CD with a .gitlab-ci.yml configuration file.

Configure Your Docker Containers:
Ensure that your Docker containers are set up to handle HTTPS. This typically involves configuring your web server (e.g., Nginx or Apache) to use SSL certificates. If you don't have SSL certificates, you may consider using Let's Encrypt to obtain them.

Create GitLab CI/CD Configuration:
In your project, create or update the .gitlab-ci.yml file. Here is a simple example:
stages:

- test

services:

- docker:dind

variables:
CONTAINER_IMAGE: your-docker-image:latest

before_script:

- docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY

test:
script:
- docker pull $CONTAINER_IMAGE
- docker run -d --name app-container -p 443:443 $CONTAINER_IMAGE
- sleep 10  # Give some time for the container to start
- curl -k https://localhost:443  # Use -k to ignore SSL certificate verification for testing
- docker stop app-container
- docker rm app-container

Replace your-docker-image with the actual name of your Docker image.

Handling SSL Certificates:
If you are using self-signed certificates or testing certificates, use the -k option with curl to ignore SSL certificate verification. In production, you should have valid SSL certificates.

GitLab CI/CD Variables:
In your GitLab project, go to Settings > CI/CD > Variables and add the necessary variables, such as CI_REGISTRY_USER and CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD, which are required for pulling your Docker image from the GitLab Container Registry.

Securely Managing Secrets:
Make sure to securely manage your secrets. Never expose sensitive information directly in your CI/CD configuration. Use GitLab CI/CD variables to store and manage secrets.

Adjusting for Your Specific Setup:
Adjust the configuration based on your specific Docker setup, web server configuration, and any other requirements of your application.

Remember to adapt these steps according to your specific use case, security requirements, and infrastructure setup. Additionally, regularly check for updates and best practices related to Docker, GitLab CI/CD, and web application security.